# MS Access Auto De-link and Re-link an Excel file?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a link-table from an Excel file, but sometimes it "breaks" for reasons unknown to me (other people manipulate this file externally and for whatever reason, the link in the database corrupts even though the filename is the same, etc).

The only way I can fix this issue is by delinking the file and then re-linking it. Is there a way to do this automatically when someone opens the database? (I know about autoexec macros and VBA and everything, but I was unable to find VBA code to delete the old link and re-link the file again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the file path does not change you can simply relink the source. You can do it to connect all the linked tables to be connected or you can specifically tell one linked table to be reconnected.

pseudo would be:

- Go through your table collection
- check if the table is a linked table / or any condition
- use the **.Connect** property to set/renew the connectionstring/path for linked tables.
- use the **.RefreshLink** method to reconnect the table

in code it would be something like this:

```
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If tdf.connect <> vbNullString Then
        'you can renew the connectionstring if you want by
        'tdf.connect = Your_connectionString & ";TABLE=" & tdf.name
        'and to reconnect
        tdf.RefreshLink 
    End If
Next tdf
```